# How to create a dojox.grid.DataGrid

Tags: dojo, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am fairly new in creating a web app builder, and I am trying to find a way to create a DataGrid using dojo. 
In one of the in panel customized widgets, I have  a combobox that has a list of companies and I would like to style that list in a grid form that contains four columns.

the js file:

```
    populateList: function (results) {  

        var zone;  
        var values = [];  
        var testVals = {}; 
        var xno;
        var zoneLowerCase;
        var EboID;
        //Loop through the QueryTask results and populate an array  
        //console.log(results.features);

        var features = results.features;  
        array.forEach(features, function (feature) {  
            zone = feature.attributes.gesbez_kurz;
            zoneLowerCase = zone.toLowerCase();
            xno = feature.attributes.strXNo;
            tt = feature.attributes.strTreatyType;
            cntry = feature.attributes.UWTCountry;
            Renewal = feature.attributes.Renewal;
            EboID = feature.attributes.intEboID;

            if (((cntry == CountrySelection) || (CountrySelection == "All Countries")) &&  (Renewal == ToggleYear)) { 
                values.push({
                name: zone + ' | ' + xno + ' | ' + tt + ' ['+ EboID +']',  //labelling,
                expid: feature.attributes.intExpID, 
                sortName: zoneLowerCase
                }); 

            }
        });

    var dataItems = {  
            identifier: "name",
            label: "name",              
            items: values
            };

        var store = new Memory({data: dataItems, idProperty: "items"});
        var storeSorted = store.query({}, {sort: [{attribute: "sortName"},{attribute: "name"}]})  
        var store = new Memory({data: storeSorted, idProperty: "items"}); 
        console.log(store);

        this.mySelect.set("store", store); 

    }
```

Comment: Which version of Web AppBuilder are you using?

Comment: I am using Web AppBuilder v1.3 Developer Edition